# How to set portrait and landscape constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout

i have two textfields, and i want to do that in portrait mode one textfield should be in one row and other one in other row but in the landscape mode both should be in single row. 
How could i achieve that via autolayout.

Comment: Please see constraints with size classes.

Answer (score 0):

Set first text filed and second text field to have equal widths. cntrl and drag from from first text filed to second textfield and choose Equal Widths.Attach the leading edge of first text filed to the leading edge of its superview, and attach the trailing edge of second textfield to the trailing edge of the superview

Comment: I think you are misssing something cause it is not working as i expected.

Comment: this may be help you to understand about autolayout . https://codeburst.io/understanding-auto-layout-constraints-part-1-844474e81d1e